# Need HTMLElement API: click() equivalent for IE6+

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to trigger a click event when enter key is pressed but i'm not sure of a way to do it for ie6

Comment: It's `click()`, it was supported in IE6 and later.

Comment: OK, how to support IE6 in three easy steps Step 1: prepare a stiff drink Step 2: get jQuery Step 3: if it doesn't work, start drinking.

Comment: @Teemu — No, it isn't. Support for that wasn't added until IE8.

Comment: @mplungjan boosts the alcohol industry, I suppose.

Comment: @Teemu — https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_htmlelement_click

Comment: @Teemu [also MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: @Quentin , VLAZ `element.click` method was supported in early days too, [see an old DHTML guide page](https://imgur.com/PXI7hNj). This of course is not exactly the same as `HTMLElement.click` ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
if (document.attachEvent) {
  document.attachEvent("keypress", function(e) { 
    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode
    if (keyCode === 13) document.getElementById("button1").click()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this on IE6, there you go (make sure this is run in IE<9 only):

```
var input = document.getElementById('some_input'), // Presumably an input element
    element = document.getElementById('some_element'); // The element to click
input.attachEvent('onkeydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) {return;} // Quit, no ENTER pressed
    element.click();
    // Prevents the default action of the event
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = false;
    return;
});
```

`keydown` needs to be listened, since `keypress` doesn't detect ENTER, and `keyup` is not cancelable. If the element ENTER was pressed on, is `input` element, you've to prevent the default action to prevent a form being submitted. Some early IE versions submitted a form on the page even when the input was outside of the form. If the element you're going to hit ENTER is not an input element, or you don't have any forms on the page, the default action preventing is not needed.